# 404 error. Too long Ajax url

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I am sending form data using Ajax

```
function sendData(){

    var formData = $('form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url:'/../admin/ajaxUtility.cfc?method=saveFormData',
        data: formData
    }); 
};
```

Above function works fine but sometimes I am sending huge data which makes url too long.

I am getting '404 Not Found' error with 'XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{25f2f525-....} Line Number 1, Column 1:' in console window.

Is their any alternate way to send data using Ajax?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Try using POST and putting the data in the body, instead of using a GET and appending everything to the URL

Comment: Can you not send it as POST instead of GET?

Comment: Add `type:'POST'` to your AJAX options and update your server side code to use `POST` data instead of `GET`

Comment: Thank you all for input. Yes, POST type was missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function sendData(){

    var formData = $('form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",   // TRIED THIS ONE ?
        url : '/../admin/ajaxUtility.cfc?method=saveFormData',
        data : formData
    }); 

} // ';' not needed at this point
```

<sub>Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#entry-examples</sub>

Comment: Thank you. POST was missing.

Answer (score 2):

I have added POST type and it works fine.

```
function sendData(){

    var formData = $('form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url:'/../admin/ajaxUtility.cfc?method=saveFormData',
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        data: formData
    }); 
};
```